# Cache busting by appending something to the filename?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I found the following text on the internet...

> **Why use cache busting?**
>
> A convenient practice that comes in handy in
> both development and production is to prevent the browser from keeping
> stale copies of the  CSS / Javascript of the application.
>
> This prevents customers from viewing a stale version of the
> application that no longer matches the Html, and avoids bug reports
> that are sometimes hard to link back to the presence of stale
> resources.
>
> The most effective way to achieve cache busting is to append to each
> CSS/Javascript file a hash of its content. This way when the file
> changes, the file name also changes and the browser will load the
> latest version of the resource.

... and I generally get the idea. However, I don't understand exactly how the filename changes just by appending a parameter to the query. For instance, how does changing the following ...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

... to ...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css?v=3.4.1">
```

... really change the filename? As far as I can see, the filename is still `style.css`. The only thing different is that there is now a parameter `v=3.4.1` at the end, but that is not the filename! Why is this?

Comment: because when you send a querystring, you typically want different data...

Comment: I am not questioning why we need "different data". I already understand the need for new and fresh data. But what I am puzzled about is why this is considered filename changing? And how the browser is tricked into thinking the file has changed simply by appending a parameter to the query.

Comment: I think the text is just using sloppy wording. They meant that the URL changes, not the filename.

Comment: Because you are requesting different data. For example you want to query a phone book. `phonebook?name=pete` should not return the same data as `phonebook.php?name=bob` but multiple calls to `?name=pete` should return the same info.

Comment: @Barmar Perfect! That makes sense, thank you.